# Dict comprehension issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-comprehension

Given this tuple:

```
my_tuple = ('chess', ['650', u'John - Tom'])
```

I want to create dictionary where `chess` is the key. It should result in:

```
my_dict = {'chess': ['650', u'John - Tom']}
```

I have this code

```
my_dict = {key: value for (key, value) in zip(my_tuple[0], my_tuple[1])}
```

but it's flawed and results in:

```
{'c': '650', 'h': u'John - Tom'}
```

Can you please help me fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> my_tuple = ('a', [1, 2], 'b', [3, 4])
>>> dict(zip(*[iter(my_tuple)]*2))
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

For your particular case though:

```
{my_tuple[0]: my_tuple[1]}
```

Comment: +1, this is the best flexible solution, although I'm still not sure the OP needs it.

Comment: @Lattyware I added a note for OP's particular case

Answer (score 4):

You can always create a dictionary from a list of tuples, (or single tuple) with 2 values.

Like so:

```
>>> my_tuple = ('chess', ['650', u'John - Tom'])
>>> d = dict([my_tuple])
>>> d
{'chess': ['650', u'John - Tom']}
```

---

In this easy way you could also have a list of tuples...

```
>>> my_tuple_list = [('a','1'), ('b','2')]
>>> d = dict(my_tuple_list)
>>> d
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```

Comment: but OP doesn't have a list of tuples

Comment: @jamylak You are correct, that is why it is in the secondary part of my answer. The first part simply explains that it is possible to use the same "method" in both cases and that is simple. (your post also suggests a more robust solution, why do you criticize my answer?)

Comment: I was not criticizing your answer, it does give insight into the `dict` constructor as you said. I was just saying OP doesn't have that data structure

Answer (score 3):

Something like this , if your tuple looks like : `(key1,value1,key2,value2,...)`

```
In [25]: dict((my_tuple[i],my_tuple[i+1]) for i in xrange(0,len(my_tuple),2))
Out[25]: {'chess': ['650', 'John - Tom']}
```

using dict-comprehension:

```
In [26]: {my_tuple[i]: my_tuple[i+1] for i in xrange(0,len(my_tuple),2)}
Out[26]: {'chess': ['650', 'John - Tom']}
```

if the number of items in tuple are not so large:

```
In [27]: { k : v for k,v in zip( my_tuple[::2],my_tuple[1::2] )}
Out[27]: {'chess': ['650', 'John - Tom']}
```

Using an iterator:

```
In [36]: it=iter(my_tuple)

In [37]: dict((next(it),next(it)) for _ in xrange(len(my_tuple)/2))
Out[37]: {'chess': ['650', 'John - Tom']}
```

Comment: +1 But you may as well use the 2.7 syntax since OP has stated 2.7

Comment: I don't really see how this is needed for the OP's problem - as far as I can tell, the OP isn't talking about a longer tuple than two values. Iteration by index is also a poor way to do it, instead, I'd use [`itertools`' `grouper()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: @Lattyware This method is fine for the OP's needs as long as he isn't working with generators and since it does say *tuple* it should be good

Comment: Well technically it answers the question of using a dict comprehension, I kinda cheated that part

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> my_tuple = ('chess', ['650', u'John - Tom'])
>>> it = iter(my_tuple)
>>> {k: next(it) for k in it}
{'chess': ['650', u'John - Tom']}

>>> my_tuple = ('a', [1, 2], 'b', [3, 4])
>>> it = iter(my_tuple)
>>> {k: next(it) for k in it}
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]}
```